# Recommendation for switch with 4 or more 10GbE SFP+ ports

Tags: networking, switch

Things are moving fast in the 10G market. I'm looking for a cheap switch (almost any kind of switch, probably all 10G will be managed to some extent) with at least 4 and ideally 8 ports capable of taking either 10G OM2 LC connections or (more likely) taking SFP+ transceivers connecting OM2 LC cable.

The connected servers all use Chelsio T420-CR's with Finisar SFP+ transceivers and OM2 cable, if that helps. I usually buy 2nd hand on EBay and I would ideally like an option that is either cheap new, or turns up used reasonably often on EBay. I'm in the EU so I'm limited to models sold in the EU.

As "cheap" is subjective let's say, whatever is available, the cheapest models out there, whether new or used.

Comment: A quick google search turned up a bunch of stuff - would you ever be looking for more than 8 ports? The prices I was seeing (new, about $1500) included an 8 port Netgear switch and a 24 port Dell switch (Powerconnect 8024F)

Comment: Not more than 8, no. Pain in searching is that SFP+ doesn't always mean 10G, and 10G doesn't always mean SFP+, and a lot of switches have loads of 1G and 2 10G SFP+ which again isn't really what I need. How did you search?

Comment: I searched this: "10 gbps fiber switch". By searching for fiber I hoped to eliminate RJ-45/10Gb copper switches. All of the fiber switches were SFP+

Comment: Ooooh check this out! I found it by accident, only $600 (but only available for pre-order). https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1318635-REG/ubiquiti_networks_us_16_xg_unifi_switch_12xsfp.html?utm_medium=Email%201640623&utm_campaign=Newsletter&utm_source=Newsletter%20170315&utm_content=Retail&utm_term=US-16-XG-Unifi-Switch-16

Comment: @NoahL - blimey! (as they say here). What a find! Thank you!  **UPDATE:** There's also an existing almost identical model (ES-16-XG not US-16-XG) which also does layer 3 routing (which the US model doesn't) *and* is on sale (not beta), for similar price. Spec suggests nothing else lost to gain the extra benefits. Fussy on transceivers but mine look compatible. Wouldn't have found it without your help + this site.  Price £542 inc VAT: http://broadbandbuyer.com/products/26485-ubiquiti-es-16-xg ... except that Amazon showed a near-new ex-store demo model for under half of that. K'ching! Thanks;-)

Comment: Update - I heard quality control concerns about ubiquity, and ended up buying a 2nd hand netgear. Very comprehensive GUI/acl etc, and  far more reputation.